# Convert a Map to a regular object

Tags: javascript

I need to merge a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance w/ an object. This didn't work:

```
> map = new Map([ ['foo', 1] ])
Map { 'foo' => 1 }
> Object.assign({}, map)
{}
```

Looks like `Object.assign` doesn't like maps.

Is there a nice, es6 way for converting maps to objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to an array via `Array.from` or the spread operator, then reduce that to an object, using the existing object as the initial value.

This will prefer the `Map` keys over any existing object keys.

```js
const map = new Map([ ['foo', 1] ])
const mergeSource = {foo: 3, bar: 4}

const obj = [...map].reduce((o, [k,v]) => ({...o, [k]: v}), mergeSource)

console.info(obj)
```

---

If the existing object keys should take priority, reverse the reduce callback expression

```
(o, [k,v]) => ({[k]: v, ...o})
```

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, I couldn't find a cleaner way than iterating through the entries and building up an object:

```js
const map = new Map([ ['foo', 1], ['bar', 2] ]);

const output = {};
for (const [key, value] of map) {
  output[key] = value;
}
console.log(output);
```

Caveat: This will overwrite any keys with the same string value, with the latter one winning.

Comment: That's a good point to make about the `Map` keys. A `Map` could have keys `1` and `"1"`  but the final object will only support string keys

Answer (score 1):

There is not a builtin method but you can do something like

```js
let map = new Map([ ['foo', 1] ]);

let obj = { bar: 2 };

const merge = (map, obj2) => {
   return Object.assign({}, obj2, ...Array.from(map).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})));
}

console.log(merge(map, obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through entries and add them to your object. This assumes keys as string. If not, they would be automatically converted to string

```js
const to_obj = ( map => {
    const obj = {};
    map.forEach ((v,k) => { obj[k] = v });
    return obj;
});

// --------------------------------------------------
// test
const m = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]);
console.log ( to_obj (m) );
// { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```